# How to implement "Open Link in new Tab" without using HTML anchors (a) tags

Tags: java, gwt

How to implement *"Open Link in new Tab"* without dealing with HTML anchors (a)?

That is, for plain divs? Using anchor this is just by adding `href` attribute

How about for plain `div`s?

Comment: What does this have to do with java?

Comment: @MouseEvent: GWT is a Java to JS compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a user action, add a click handler. Open a new window in `onClick`. If this is a code-driven action, just call this method:

```
Window.open("http://myApp.com/", "_blank", "");
```

Comment: It can be done with any handler, including ContextMenuHandler.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Anchor as follows:

```
Anchor your_link = new Anchor("some text", "http://your.fancy.url.com", "_blank");
```